# So, how to remove Rack::ShowExceptions from inside my rack app?

Tags: ruby, rack, httpserver

I write own little http app based on rack. And this code is to initialize rack. (This is not sinatra, not rails, not hanami app).

```
ENV['RACK_ENV']='deployment'
# some more initializations
# end then
@rack = Rack::Server.new(
    app: Router.new,
    Host: Cfg.http.host,
    Port: Cfg.http.port,
    Logger: Log,
    environment: Cfg.env.to_s
)
```

But if I crash my app I see in browser all that crap from Rack::ShowExceptions.

How can I completely disable, remove it, without need to patching rack sources?

Comment: As you could see, I had set ENV variable in my code before rack init, but this does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
@rack = Rack::Server.new(
    # ...
    environment: :none
)
```

I've open my eyes and found that in comments here https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb#L157-L162